# Exporting contact's directly to database without downloading

Tags: php, mysql, magento, mysqli, prestashop

I am looking/making a script. I am just not sure if it's gonna work. I have some online stores using prestashop and magento. The users can subscribe to newsletter's there. Everytime i want to export the subscribers i need to download the .csv file and uploaded it to my database were my subscribers are located.
I would like to make or find a script that allows me to hit export and the script should export the contact directly to the database with the subscribers, without download the file.

I was planning on changing the existing export script with something like this, would this be appropriate, or does anyone have a better and easier solution?:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="test";
$tbl_name="subscribers";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("error");
mysql_select_db("test", $link) or die ("Connection fail");

$id = $_POST['id']; 
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$custom_fields = $_POST['custom_fields'];
$list = $_POST['list'];
$unsubscribed = $_POST['unsubscribed'];
$bounced = $_POST['bounced'];
$bounce_soft = $_POST['bounce_soft'];
$complaint = $_POST['complaint'];
$last_campaing = $_POST['last_campaing'];
$last_ares = $_POST['last_ares'];
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
$join_date = $_POST['join_date'];
$confirmed = $_POST['confirmed'];
$messageID = $_POST['messageID'];

$sql="INSERT INTO test(id, userID, name, email, custom_fields, list, unsubscribed, bounced, bounce_soft, complaint, last_campaing, last_ares, timestamp, join_date, confirmed, messageID)VALUES('$id', '$userID', '$name', '$email', '$custom_fields', '$list', '$unsubscribed', '$bounced', '$bounce_soft', '$complaint', '$last_campaing', '$last_ares', '$timestamp', '$join_date', '$confirmed', '$messageID')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
   echo "error";
}
?>
<?php
 mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get a module for both. But that script will not work. You need to look if you server grants remote access to your store database and use the correct path.